# UITextView in UITableViewCell - Problem with Tags

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

i have a Grouped TableView with textfields in the UITableViewCells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}


if(indexPath.section < 6) {
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10,580, 31)];
    textField.tag = indexPath.section + 22;
    textField.delegate = self;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
    [textField release];
}
return cell;
}
```

So when i press the Save Button, the saveItem Method is called:

```
- (void)saveItem {
    NSMutableArray *textFieldArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i <6; i++) {
        [textFieldArray addObject:(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:22+i]];
    }
...
}
```

I can change the values of the first 4 TextFields without a problem. they are also saved, but when i change a value in the 5th or 6th Textfield, my app crashes and i get an error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0'

Any suggestions?

Thanks so far.

Comment: Are all six sections displayed?

Comment: Yes, they are also filled with the right values.

Comment: Should you also only be adding the textfield when you are creating a new cell, at the moment you are adding a textfield to cells that may already have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in that: *not all* sections are displayed when you tap **Save button**. So when you try to access `view` with tag 5 and 6 they are nil because they are not displayed and so were't added (or were removed) from your view.

To test this just try to scroll to bottom of your `tableView` and try to tap **Save button**.

Comment: Okay it works, when i close the keyboard and have all cells visible. so how can i access them with the keyboard hiding them?

Comment: You should save values from that `textField`s in some variables in `UITableViewController`, otherwise you will lost their values.

Comment: Okay it works now perfect with `textFieldDidEndEditing`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1.what ever your trying to access that object is unavailable to you.which means [self.view viewWithTag:22+i] giving nil.

2.tableview wont allocate memory to all the cells.it allocates memory only for which you can visible.

3.once scroll your tableview and once see the 6th section then press the save button your app will not be crash.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to modify your code

```
if(indexPath.section <= 6) {     
     UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10,580, 31)];     
     textField.tag = indexPath.section + 22;     
     textField.delegate = self;     
     [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];     
     [textField release]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, ty not to create the textField in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You should create it in your `init` or `viewDidLoad` methods.